# Deploy 3rd-party jar to clojars?

Tags: java, maven, clojure, leiningen

I'm using a 3rd-party open source Java library with my Clojure project.  It's not available in Maven Central or at Clojars.  I can create a pom file and figure out how to install it a Maven Central, but--I am lazy and I am used to the increased convenience of Clojure tools such as Leiningen!  Is there a convenient way to deploy the 3rd party jar to Clojars?  There's no need to build it first; it's already been built. (The Java library uses the tried and true--`make`.)

If I must give up my laziness, I will, but if not, why bother?  (On the other hand, I've already probably spent more time trying this and that, reading Leiningen documentation and blog posts, and asking this question here, than I would have spent if I'd just sat down and made a pom file, etc.  I've been unable to find an answer, so far.  Laziness is time-consuming!)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

First, I wouldn't install a jar for which you don't own the copyright in a public place.

The easiest way to have access to an arbitrary jar via Maven/Leiningen would be to "install" the jar int your local repository. For example, if want your dependency to look like`[com.example.foo/bar "1.0.0"]`, you would install it with the `mvn` command.

```
mvn -Dfile=your.jar \
    -DgroupId=com.example.foo \
    -DartifactId=bar \
    -Dversion=1.0.0 \
    -Dpackaging=jar \
    -DgeneratePom=true
```

This makes the dependency available only to you. If you're on a team, you could require each person to run this command. However, if you don't mind spending a little money, you could host your own repository on S3 using [s3-wagon-private](https://github.com/s3-wagon-private/s3-wagon-private).

There's also repository managers like [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/index.cgi), [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/), and NEXUS.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy.  What I'm trying to do is to make my Clojure app easy to download and use for anyone who wants to play with it.  I'm trying to figure out how to make this as easy as possible.  This is why I'd like the library to be in a public place.  That's a reasonable point about copyright ownership.  I'm pretty sure I can get permission from the copyright holder to put the library up at maven.org.