# Clojure / Leiningen - package jar resource into clojars

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojars

I have a question similar to [Deploy 3rd-party jar to clojars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570911/deploy-3rd-party-jar-to-clojars)

I've pushed a small project into clojars using `lein deploy`. That project relies on a jar dependency that I've simply put in a folder on the local drive and imported in my `:resource-paths` as per below:

```
(defproject cljblpapiwrapper "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description ""
  :url ""
  :license {:name "" :url ""}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]]
  :resource-paths ["resources/blpapi-3.8.8-2.jar"]
  :repl-options {:init-ns cljblpapiwrapper.core})
```

Now upon importing my deployed clojars repo in another project, it fails to find classes within the jar repo. I'm getting this trace:

```
#error {
 :cause com.bloomberglp.blpapi.CorrelationID
 :via
 [{:type clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException
   :message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.bloomberglp.blpapi.CorrelationID, compiling:(cljblpapiwrapper/core.clj:6:1)
   :at [clojure.lang.Compiler load Compiler.java 7526]}
  {:type java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
   :message com.bloomberglp.blpapi.CorrelationID
   :at [java.net.URLClassLoader findClass URLClassLoader.java 382]}]
 :trace
 [[java.net.URLClassLoader findClass URLClassLoader.java 382]
  [clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader findClass DynamicClassLoader.java 69]
  [java.lang.ClassLoader loadClass ClassLoader.java 424]
  [clojure.lang.DynamicClassLoader loadClass DynamicClassLoader.java 77]
  [java.lang.ClassLoader loadClass ClassLoader.java 357]
...
```

Looks to me like the jar didn't make it to clojars - how can I package it within my repo? Alternatively, how can I push it separately to clojars?

thanks,

Comment: @AlanThompson thanks for this - I unpacked and the library is there (goes into top folder e.g. where I extract). Do you know how I should reference it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to download your lib from clojars? Use the `jar` command to unpack the *.jar file and see if the lib is there.

Look at this repo:   https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo-datomic

In the `./resources` dir there is a jar file:  `datomic-free-0.9.5661-everything.jar`

You may need to play around with the syntax in `project.clj` to make the uberjar on clojars form correctly.  You may need to publish the dependency JAR file on a separate maven-compatible repo. Options include:

- [Deps.co](https://www.deps.co/)  -  Created by the host of The REPL podcast
- AWS S3 - there is [a lein plugin](https://github.com/s3-wagon-private/s3-wagon-private) to help with this

Comment: I ended up packaging the jar into a clojars repo using a script I found at https://github.com/tulos/bberg-sdk . Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to bind the jar as dependency in your project.clj, resource path tells uber jar just include the file.